# Use blog as base for tags and categories

Tags: categories, redirect, tags, blog

I have a site: `example.com` build in wordpress. I set up the posts page as `example.com/news`.

I want my tags and categories to be:

```
example.com/news/tag/mytag
example.com/news/category/mycategory
```

instead of

```
example.com/tag/mytag
example.com/category/mycategory
```

Any idea how I can do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom Permalink in setting.
See bellow screenshot..
[image]